# Struggling with libssh on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, libssh

## The problem

I'm trying to build a project in Visual Studio 2015 on Win10 that makes use of libssh, but I'm having no luck getting it to work. I feel like I'm losing my mind here. I'm either completely blanking out or missing something incredibly obvious.

I've tried using the installer libssh-0.7.2-msvc.exe from the files section at https://red.libssh.org/projects/libssh/files. I then linked it to a test C++ project in VS2015. Using the sample code I'm able to compile it:

```
#include <iostream>

#define LIBSSH_STATIC
#include <libssh/libssh.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Starting libssh test" << std::endl;

    ssh_session my_ssh_session = ssh_new();

    if (my_ssh_session == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize" << std::endl;
    }

    ssh_free(my_ssh_session);

    return 0;
}
```

(**Note:** I've tried both `#define LIBSSH_STATIC` and `#define LIBSSH_STATIC 1` based on posts I've seen from my initial search for answers. I've even tried adding it to the preprocessor definitions in project properties.)

I can only compile it if my project is set to 32-bit, but I can't run the resulting executable. Doing so results in an error: "The code execution cannot proceed because ssh.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem." I'm statically linking ssh.lib, though, so I'm not sure why I'm even getting that error.

So I tried compiling libssh myself as 64-bit. It took some more tinkering than I expected (I had some issues with zlib, which eventually I just omitted since it's optional). I can compile my project as a 64-bit executable successfully, but once again, I can't actually *run* it. I get the same error about ssh.dll being missing.

For the sake of trying it, I removed the LIBSSH_STATIC define and tried to link just to the DLL. Copying the ssh.dll from the libssh distribution into my program folder and trying to run it, I get the error: "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application."

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but I'm sure it's dumb and I'm overthinking it.

## Project settings (all configurations, all platforms)

libssh is installed to `G:\Libraries\libssh_0.7.2` on my machine.

**Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories**

- `G:\Libraries\libssh_0.7.2\include;$(IncludePath)`

**Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Library Directories**

- `G:\Libraries\libssh_0.7.2\lib;$(LibraryPath)`

**Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies**

- `ssh.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)`

## libssh path summary

- libssh_0.7.2

  - bin

    - *ssh.dll*
  - include

    - libssh

      - *callbacks.h*
      - *legacy.h*
      - *libssh.h*
      - *libsshpp.hpp*
      - *server.h*
      - *sftp.h*
      - *ssh2.h*
  - lib

    - *ssh.lib*

Comment: You need to put ssh.dll in a place where your program can find it. Somewhere in the %PATH% is one choice. In the same directory your progrsm is living is another.

Comment: I tried that. That's what I mentioned at the end: When the DLL is visible to the program, it fails to load with the "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)" error.

Comment: 0xc000007b usually means your program is trying to load a wrong dll. Either not the right architecture (32 vs 64 bits) or corrupt or a version incompatible with that it was linked with.

Comment: I've tried both architectures. Using the lib/dll provided by libssh, it won't compile on 64 bit. It compiles on 32 bit but throws that error. But the dll and lib I'm using are from the same installation, so I don't see how they would be mismatched. Likewise if I build libssh myself, I get that error using the resulting dll and lib which come from the same build. This is why it's driving me nuts, because I can't seem to find an obvious cause. :(

Comment: LastError 123 is `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` Try to put the DLL in Dependency Walker. Also, try to just build a little C program, with NO reference to shh, and use ` LoadLibrary`, to see if the DLL is "loadable".

Answer (score 1):

1. Install `vkpkg`
2. <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and open the powershell
3. Input `vckpg install libssh:x64-windows`
4. Integrate into Visual Studio: vcpkg integrate install

Then you can include `<libssh.h>` in Visual Studio.